# Creating an API of ML model using Flask in Python

Tags: python, json, api, flask

I want to create an API of my ML model using flask.
The model simply takes an image and classifies it.
I want to upload the pickle file of my model and want the user to dynamically upload the image file at the runtime as an argument for my functionality to run.

Following is the code snippet i have tried but there is some issue as i am not able to retrieve the files from my hard disk:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
import os
from tensorflow import keras as tfk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Image Classifier!"

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/image_reader/<path:image_path>/<pickle_file>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def image_classification(image_path):
    if request.json:
        data = request.get_json(image_path)

        image_path = data.get("image_path")
        print(image_path)
        r = requests.get(image_path, timeout=60)

        # save the image to disk
        temp_file = 'tmp/temp.jpg'
        f = open(temp_file, "wb")
        f.write(r.content)
        f.close()

        model = pickle.load(pickle_file)

        return image_path
    else:
        return "no json received"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Initially, I am simply trying to take both the above mentioned parameters i.e. uploading pickle_file and taking dynamic file path from user as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file, it's stored in `request.files` which is a dictionnary.

Instead what you should do is something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests
import os
from tensorflow import keras as tfk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Image Classifier!"

@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route('/image_reader', methods=['POST'])
def image_classification():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        image_file = request.file.get('image_path')        
        pickle_file = request.file.get('pickle_file')

        # save the image to disk
        temp_file = 'tmp/temp.jpg'
        image_file.save(temp_file)

        # Save the pickle file to disk
        temp_picke_file = 'tmp/model.pickle'
        pickle_file.save(temp_pickle_file)

        # Load the model using the pickle file
        model = pickle.load(open(temp_pickle_file,'w'))

        return "Image saved to " + temp_file


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Here is the official flask doc about uploading files: <https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/>

Comment: I am not sure how to provide the image_path as input while hitting the url: "localhost:5000/image_reader". Should i provide the path in the URL itself? Something like,  "localhost:5000/image_reader/C:\\Users\\Desktop\\file.png"? How should i provide the file_path to program?

Comment: What are you using to make a request ? Are you simply using your web browser ?